# How to make format() yield numeric objects

Tags: r, format

Whenever I format a table as such:

```
example <- sample(LETTERS, replace = T)
format(table(example), scientific = T)
```

The numbers become characters.  How can I tell `format()` my object is numeric without resorting to `as.numeric()`? I can't find any such parameters in the function's help page. It says that `format()` objects are usually numeric, so I guess I'm missing some basic command.

My real data looks like this:

```
> xtabs(...)
      PRU/DF      PSU/ILH      PSU/JFA      PSU/MCL      PSU/SRM      PSU/ULA 
1.040771e+01 0.000000e+00 2.280347e-01 0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00 8.186240e+00 
     PSU/URA      PSU/VGA        PU/AC        PU/AM        PU/AP        PU/BA 
0.000000e+00 1.534169e+01 8.184747e+01 1.410106e+01 1.028717e+01 1.099289e+00 
       PU/GO        PU/MA        PU/MG        PU/MT        PU/PA        PU/PI 
0.000000e+00 4.369910e+01 5.350849e+00 0.000000e+00 4.706721e-01 0.000000e+00
```

I want to have the console print the numbers prettier so my co-workers don't have a heart attack. This is what I've come up with:

```
> format(xtabs(...), scientific = F, digits = 1)
   PRU/DF   PSU/ILH   PSU/JFA   PSU/MCL   PSU/SRM   PSU/ULA   PSU/URA   PSU/VGA 
"10.4077" " 0.0000" " 0.2280" " 0.0000" " 0.0000" " 8.1862" " 0.0000" "15.3417" 
    PU/AC     PU/AM     PU/AP     PU/BA     PU/GO     PU/MA     PU/MG     PU/MT 
"81.8475" "14.1011" "10.2872" " 1.0993" " 0.0000" "43.6991" " 5.3508" " 0.0000" 
    PU/PA     PU/PI     PU/RO     PU/RR     PU/TO    PRU/RJ   PSU/CPS   PSU/NRI 
" 0.4707" " 0.0000" "40.6327" "10.3247" " 0.0000" "10.9644" " 0.0000" "55.4122"
```

I'd like to get rid of those quotes so the data looks better on the console.

Comment: what's the end result you're going for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `format` function returns character vectors with the numbers now "formatted" per your specifications.  If you convert the result back to numbers then any formatting is now lost.  I think your problem may be rather the difference between creating the formatted output and printing the formatted output.  When you create an object, but don't do anything with it, the object is automatically printed using default arguments, one of the defaults is to put quotes around the character strings.  If you don't want the quotes then just call `print` yourself and tell it to not include the quotes:

```
> example <- sample(LETTERS, replace = T)
> print(format(table(example), scientific = T), quote=FALSE)
example
B E F G H J K L Q S T U W X Z 
1 1 1 2 1 2 3 1 1 1 3 1 1 5 2
```

If your main goal is to not use scientific notation then you should look at the `zapsmall` function which will turn extremely small values (often the culprit in switching to scientific notation) into zeros.  Or do `options(scipen=5)` (or some other value than 5) which will reduce the likelihood of switching to scientific notation in subsequent printing.

Answer (score 1):

Format returns character vectors, so this is in general to be expected. Your problem, I think, results from the fact that the "format" representation of an *integer* vector `c( 1, 2, 3)` is `"1" "2" "3"`, whereas the representation of a *numeric* (real) vector `c( 1, 2, 3 )` is `"1e+00"  "2e+00" "3e+00"`.

Consider the following:

```
format( 1:10 )
format( 1:10, scientific= TRUE )
format( as.numeric( 1:10 ), scientific= TRUE )
```

Therefore, try

```
format( as.numeric( table( example ) ), scientific= TRUE )
```

Unfortunately, you cannot omit the `as.numeric`, since `table` generates integer values, and you need real.

Comment: Thanks for the reminder on integer vs. vectors, I hadn't paid attention to it. However, `format(as.numeric(table(...)))` still yields character values. On the other hand, `as.numeric(format(table(...)))` works, but then I lose the table labels and get nothing but a character vector.

Comment: Yes. Because `format` returns character vectors. For printing. That is the whole point of this function :-). Maybe you should look into option( digits= ... ) or something?

Answer (score 0):

From your comments on @January's answer, it appears you're just looking for `c(table(example))`.

Comment: Thanks for the input, but that's not quit it. I'll edit my question in order to make it more clear.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution I've found:

```
View(format(xtabs(...), scientific = F, digits = 1))
```

The table will appear in another window instead of inside the console, like I originally wanted, but it solves my problem of quickly showing pretty data without resorting to long commands. More elegant solutions are welcome!